# Emberjs: How do I filter users by any property using routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I have the following route and model setup. All my users display fine using a template and
displays the firstName and email as expected. 
However I am unable to filter by firstName or email when routing similar to how :user_id works. (I am using the fixture adapter for now)

Example: #/users/logan

```
 this.resource('users', function(){
     this.resource('user', {path: ':user_firstName'}); //#/users/logan
 });
```

The following model

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string')
})
```

So to summarise further, exactly what should happen inside the model function or what other approach can I take?

```
App.UsersRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        var user = App.User.find();;

       //FILTER BY firstName how?

        return user;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an event on the route that changes the controller content to be a filter of the model.

Template:

`<span {{action filterByName}}>Filter by name</span>`

Router:

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    filterByName: function() {
      this.get('controller').set('content', this.get('currentModel').filterProperty('firstName', 'John'));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Expanding on the above after reading the API I now have the following working.


'user = App.User.find()'
'user = this.controllerFor('users').set('content', user.filterProperty('firstName', params.firstName));'